# Running a script within cron job

Tags: linux, scripting, cron

we have a hourly.sh script that contains abc.py script.
1. when i run the abc.py script independently it runs fine.
2. when i run an empty hoursly.sh (without abc.py script inside) it runs fine too.

But when hourly.sh is ran with abc.py inside, it hits memory related issues ("16214 Segmentation fault (core dumped)"). Just to provide an additional data point, there is no other script running at the same time as this script which can put more burden on the system.

What could cause a script to fail when triggered via cron?

Comment: You should tell how do you run "hourly.sh is ran with abc.py inside" if really need help

Comment: Here is hourly.sh: $ cat cron/hourly.sh
#
#       runs every hour

#
#
exec >> ~/cron/hourly.log
exec 2>&1

python abc.py 24 1

Answer (score 1):

There's always the possiblity that the differences in runtime environment cause problems. Take a look at the process parameters (Number of files etc.) which you can select using the "ulimit" command.

Maybe take a look at quotas for the user the cronjob is run, maybe the PATH environment.